# Is there a way to use CROSS APPLY from SQL to Spark SQL?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, cross-join, databricks-sql, cross-apply

I have complex stored procedure that uses multiple views/functions inside and inside there are multiple cross applies and I am not sure if there is a "easy solution" to replicate it in spark.sql

df = spark.sql(f"""
select * from table
CROSS APPLY (
some business rule )
""")

I checked the documentation: https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html but didn`t found what I want

Comment: `apply` is a product specific construct, more generally known officially as a *lateral join*

Comment: So it will be CROSS JOIN LATERAL from what I can understand from your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first of all enable this option in your notebook

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=true")
```